# Is it possible to view my steam data for any particular date in history?

Tags: steam

I was recently talking to a friend, and I mentioned a few games I spent a large amount of time playing over a short time.

Is it possible to view data like the playtime in the last two weeks for a date in the past, or is this data removed after the two weeks have passed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell no, they only store the past 2 weeks, after that any data is removed.

You can see most of your data here: https://help.steampowered.com/en/accountdata